# SlateJS image styling

Tags: reactjs, slatejs

I'm using **SlateJS** in my React project and I'm trying to put, in editor, an image with fixed width/height (600px/200px).

In this moment, when I click a button, the code insert the image:

```
const image = {
    type: 'image',
    url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1706562018252-5ce3eadb2288?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwNzIzODM1MA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=600',
    children: [{ text: '' }]
};
Transforms.insertNodes(editor, image);
```

I've tried to specify properties width and height in the **image** const, but it doesn't work:

```
const image = {
    type: 'image',
    url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1706562018252-5ce3eadb2288?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwNzIzODM1MA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=600',
    children: [{ text: '' }],
    width: "600px",
    heigth: "200px"
};
Transforms.insertNodes(editor, image);
```

I've also tried to add a property called **style** (ChatGPT recommended it to me) but nothing:

```
const image = {
    type: 'image',
    url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1706562018252-5ce3eadb2288?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwNzIzODM1MA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=600',
    children: [{ text: '' }],
    style: {
        width: "600px",
        heigth: "200px"
    }
};
Transforms.insertNodes(editor, image);
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing"? Please share the code of your image component.

Comment: I don't have any Image component, I just use Transforms.insertNodes to add that object. Is that wrong?

Comment: Well yes... I think you should check the [official example](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/images).

Comment: Ok thanks, apologies for the lack of attention to documentation